# Append li to jcoverflip Image Gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, html-lists, reload

I have an image Gallery that looks like this:

```
<div id="mycontainer">
<div id= wrapper>
  <ul id="flip">
  <li><img id="contact" src="./Photos/PhoneMenu.png" /></li>
  <li><img id="info" src="./Photos/InfoMenu.png" /></li>
  <li><img id="home" src="./Photos/LogoMenu.png" /></li>
  <li><img id="product" src="./Photos/SignUpMenu.png" /></li>
  <li><img id="thumbs" src="./Photos/FacebookMenu.png" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

At some point, when the user clicks something, I want to add more images to this gallery. I have achieved this by doing this:

```
$("#mycontainer div ul").append('<li><img id="Coin" src="./Photos/Coin1.png" /></li>');
```

problem is, I think I need to refresh/reload the gallery, because the image is being appended to the site but never as a part of the gallery.

example: 
[image]

I have tried several things but have now come to a halt and am in dire need of help.

The gallery script is being referred to like this in my code:

```
$.getScript("./JqueryScriptFiles/Flipper.js");
```

It also has script file being called in the head tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./JqueryScriptFiles/jquery.jcoverflip.js"></script>
```

The content of Flipper.js will be in this fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/5evk9ehn/

I really hope someone can help me figure this out. Thx in advance!

Comment: Could you add a demo for the same??

Comment: i think only way is to add extra item to existing gallery for this plugin is to destroy the previously created/initialized object and again initialize the widget after adding `li`

Comment: It sounds reasonable VijayP. But how would you go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with an alternative solution to this.

Bottom line is you want some images to be visible at some point and then aditional ones at another point.

So i went on to never append the li to ul but making the li stay in the ul constantly:

```
<div id="mycontainer">
  <div id= wrapper>
    <ul id="flip">
      <li><img id="contact" src="./Photos/PhoneMenu.png" /></li>
      <li><img id="info" src="./Photos/InfoMenu.png" /></li>
      <li><img id="home" src="./Photos/LogoMenu.png" /></li>
      <li><img id="product" src="./Photos/SignUpMenu.png" /></li>
      <li><img id="thumbs" src="./Photos/FacebookMenu.png" /></li>
      <li><img id="Coin" src="./Photos/Coin1.png" /></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```

The problem is you can't just do:

```
$("#Coin").hide();
```

This you can't do because as soon as you interact with gallery the img will show again. I don't know why but it does.

So I went on and did this:

```
var Hide = setInterval(function() {
    $("#Coin").fadeTo(0, 0.00);
    $("#Coin").hide();
}, 0);
```

You have to do the fadeTo because else the img will glich everytime you interact with the gallery.

when you reach the point where you want to show the img again in the gallery you go about it like this:

```
if(//event has occured){
                clearInterval(Hide);
                $("#Coin").fadeTo(0, 1.0);
                $("#Coin").show();
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, [jcoverflip does not support directly adding or removing items](https://github.com/NewSignature/jcoverflip/wiki/Questions-and-Answers#starting-on-a-specific-item).

They list **a workaround**, though, which is whay @vijayP suggested: destroy the object, add an li, then create it again. In your case, it would look something like this:

```
var $ul = $("#mycontainer div ul");
$ul.jcoverflip('destroy');
$ul.append('<li><img id="Coin" src="./Photos/Coin1.png" /></li>');
$ul.jcoverflip();
```

Note that, in doing this, the gallery will go back to the first item. You might have to figure out which item is selected before destroying the gallery and then set it back when creating it.

**If you DO want to maintain the gallery position**:

Seems like they don't make it easy to figure out the current position. You might be able to hack it by looking for the image that has full opacity set, before destroying it:

```
var pos = 0;
$("#mycontainer div ul img").filter(function(i) {
    pos = i;
    return $(this).css("opacity") == 1;
});
```

and then using that when you reinstantiate the gallery:

```
$ul.jcoverflip({current: pos+1});
```

Note that it looks like they use 1 based indexing...weirdos ;-)

**UPDATE:**
It looks like there's more custom setup of the jcoverflow element in your example.  When you re-initialize the jcoverflip element (after destroying the original and appending the new li), I would reinitialize the element with the same code that you posted in `Flipper.js`.  I think you only need to instantiate the jcoverflip element though:

```
jQuery( '#flip' ).jcoverflip({
      current: 2, // Or whatever the currently select position in the gallery is
      beforeCss: function( el, container, offset ){
        return [
          $.jcoverflip.animationElement( el, { left: ( container.width( )/2 - 210 - 110*offset + 20*offset )+'px', bottom: '20px' }, { } ),
          $.jcoverflip.animationElement( el.find( 'img' ), { width: "4.16vw", height: "2.76vw"}, {} )
        ];
      },
      afterCss: function( el, container, offset ){
        return [
          $.jcoverflip.animationElement( el, { left: ( container.width( )/2 + 110 + 110*offset )+'px', bottom: '20px' }, { } ),
          $.jcoverflip.animationElement( el.find( 'img' ), { width: "5.20vw", height: "3.43vw"}, {} )
        ];
      },
      currentCss: function( el, container ){
        return [
          $.jcoverflip.animationElement( el, { left: ( container.width( )/2 - 100 )+'px', bottom: 0 }, { } ),
          $.jcoverflip.animationElement( el.find( 'img' ), { width: '10.41vw', height: "6.87vw" }, { } )
        ];
      },
      change: function(event, ui){
        jQuery('#scrollbar').slider('value', ui.to*25);
      }
    });
```

I don't think you need to re-instantiate the slider element, but I'm not certain about that.

Comment: when i do this the image does kinda become a part of the gallery but only in dimensions. It never animates according with the other images. I tried doing prepend(); instead and now it animates but not according to as it should. Do you know other ways one could add lists to an ul ?

Comment: in short terms. The appended li is shown correctly in the gallery with your suggestion but frozen animation wise.

Comment: Perhaps you have a slightly different setup.  I tested this by running `jQuery("#flip").jcoverflip('destroy');jQuery("#flip").append('<li><img id="Coin" src="1.png" /></li>');jQuery("#flip").jcoverflip()` on https://www.newsignature.com/wp-content/jcoverflip/jcoverflip-demo/index.html through the console, and it should work. What does the <ul> element look like before and after you run `destroy`?  Also, what does it look like after you call `jcoverflip` again?

Comment: Actually, it looks like your setup has more customized initialization of the gallery element.  It might work if you re-initialize the jcoverflip element in the same way it is done in `Flipper.js`.  See my updated answer.

Comment: I am sorry i just tried this. the appended image is still frozen in the gallery. You don't have to waste more time with this mate. I have found an alternative solution that i will post in a bit. Thank you so much for your help. If you do decide to go any further with this and find the solution then I will be happy to mark you.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad you found an alternative workaround. I was going to suggest looking for an alternative to jcoverflip since it seem to no longer be supported and doesn't even work with newer versions of jQuery, so it's apt to cause headaches.  Good luck!